# syntax error on STM32F100XB_FLASH.ld(st official linker script)

Tags: linker, stm32

I run command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -T STM32F100XB_FLASH.ld -o main.elf main.c lcd.c c2b.c startup_stm32f100xb.s system_stm32f10x.c stm32f10x_gpio.c stm32f10x_rcc.c -specs=nosys.specs
```

but got error like this

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld:STM32F100XB_FLASH.ld:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

syntax error in this file(STM32F100XB_FLASH):

```
0
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
0
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20001FFF;    /* end of RAM */
0
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */
0
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 8K
}
0
/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
0
  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)
0
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))
0
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH
0
  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
0
  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH
0
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
0
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
0
  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
0
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
0

  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
0
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM
0
  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM
0

0
  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }
0
  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Thas Linker script file publish by st.com in STM32Cube_FW_F1_V1.4.0.zip firmware file for STMCUBEMX ( I extracted that and find some file including STM32F100XB_FLASH.ld)

but when change linker script file with other one not official! compile and link successfully.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -T stm32f100.ld -o main.elf main.c lcd.c c2b.c startup_stm32f100xb.s system_stm32f10x.c stm32f10x_gpio.c stm32f10x_rcc.c -specs=nosys.specs
```

and the stm32f100.ld file:

```
/*
Linker script for STM32F10x_128K_8K

modified from

http://www.codesourcery.com/archives/arm-gnu/msg02972.html
http://communities.mentor.com/community/cs/archives/arm-gnu/msg02972.html
*/

/*
There will be a link error if there is not this amount of RAM free at the
end.
*/

_Minimum_Stack_Size = 256;

ENTRY(Reset_Handler)


/* Memory Spaces Definitions */

MEMORY
{
  RAM (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 8K
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

__ram_start__ = ORIGIN(RAM);
__ram_size__  = LENGTH(RAM);
__ram_end__   = __ram_start__ + __ram_size__;
_estack = __ram_end__;
/* highest address of the user mode stack */



PROVIDE ( _Stack_Limit = _estack - _Minimum_Stack_Size );

/* Sections Definitions */

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))            /* Startup code */
        *(.text)                   /* code */
        *(.text.*)                 /* remaining code */
        *(.rodata)                 /* read-only data (constants) */
        *(.rodata.*)
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.glue_7t)
        *(.vfp11_veneer)
        *(.v4_bx)
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } >FLASH

    /* for exception handling/unwind - some Newlib functions (in
    common with C++ and STDC++) use this. */
    .ARM.extab :
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

    } > FLASH

     __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > FLASH
        __exidx_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(4);
     _etext = .;
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .data secion
*/
    _sidata = _etext;

    /* This is the initialized data section
    The program executes knowing that the data is in the RAM
    but the loader puts the initial values in the FLASH (inidata).
    It is one task of the startup to copy the initial values from FLASH to
RAM. */
    .data  : AT ( _sidata )
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .data
secion */
        _sdata = . ;

        *(.data)
        *(.data.*)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .data
secion */
        _edata = . ;
    } >RAM


    /* This is the uninitialized data section */
    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss
secion */
        _sbss = .;
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss.*)
        *(COMMON)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss
secion */
        _ebss = . ;
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
    } >RAM

    PROVIDE ( end = _ebss );
    PROVIDE ( _end = _ebss );
    PROVIDE ( _exit = _ebss );
    PROVIDE (_stackend = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM) - _Minimum_Stack_Size);

    /* This is the user stack section
    This is just to check that there is enough RAM left for the User mode
stack
    It should generate an error if it's full.
     */
    ._usrstack :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _susrstack = . ;

        . = . + _Minimum_Stack_Size ;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _eusrstack = . ;
    } >RAM



    /* after that it's only debugging information. */

    /* remove the debugging information from the standard libraries */
/*
    DISCARD :
    {
     libc.a ( * )
     libm.a ( * )
     libgcc.a ( * )
     }
*/

    /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
    .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
    .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
    .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
    .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
    .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
    .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
    .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
    /* DWARF debug sections.
       Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
       of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
    /* DWARF 1 */
    .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
    .line           0 : { *(.line) }
    /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
    .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
    .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
    /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
    .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
    .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
    /* DWARF 2 */
    .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
    .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
    .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
    .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
    .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
    .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
    .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
    /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
    .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
    .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
    .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
    .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
}
```

Whats wrong with STM32F100XB_FLASH.ld???

Answer (score 4):

All the zeroes that you have at the beginning of lines are wrong and that's what ld is telling you.

```
0 <-- error
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
0 <-- error
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20001FFF;    /* end of RAM */
0 <-- error
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */
0 <-- error
...
```

The file in the package is indeed broken, as are all the files from this folder (`Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Source/Templates/gcc/linker/`). My suggestion would be to use any of the files from the `Projects/` folder and just change the values of flash/ram addresses and sizes to match your device (you can take them from the file which is broken).

If you just take this one - `Projects/STM32VL-Discovery/Examples/ADC/ADC_Regular_injected_groups/TrueSTUDIO/STM32VL-Discovery/STM32F100VB_FLASH.ld` - then you won't need to change anything, as the sizes and addresses are OK for your device (assuming it's a device with 128kB of flash and 8kB of RAM).